# Making a form with submit in Polymer

Tags: html, polymer

I am trying to learn polymer and I came across an awesome demo from webcomponents. Although I cant get it to work. I used the polymer starter pack option. In view 1 I want to post an form but I get errors.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu-light.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu-shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
  <style include="shared-styles">
  :host {
    display: block;

    padding: 10px;
  }
  </style>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <h1>View One</h1>
    <p>Ut labores minimum atomorum pro. Laudem tibique ut has.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per in nusquam nominavi periculis, sit elit oportere ea.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per in nusquam nominavi periculis, sit elit oportere ea.Cu mei vide viris gloriatur, at populo eripuit sit.</p>

    <form is="iron-form" method="get" action="/" id="basic">
      <paper-input name="name" label="Name" required></paper-input>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="donuts" checked> I like donuts<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="pizza" required> I like pizza<br>
      <paper-checkbox name="food" value="cheese" required>I like cheese</paper-checkbox><br>
      <paper-dropdown-menu label="Cars" name="cars" required>
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
          <paper-item value="volvo">Volvo</paper-item>
          <paper-item value="saab">Saab</paper-item>
          <paper-item value="fiat">Fiat</paper-item>
          <paper-item value="audi">Audi</paper-item>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
      <paper-button raised onclick="_submit(event)">Submit</paper-button>
      <paper-button raised onclick="_reset(event)">Reset</paper-button>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </form>


  </div>
</template>

<script>

function _submit(event) {
  Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
}
function _reset(event) {
  var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement
  form.reset();
  form.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = '';
}
basic.addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function(event) {
  this.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail);
});

</script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: can you post here the errors?

Comment: Your `dom-module` is incomplete. You are missing the JavaScript part. Your `_submit` and `_reset` methods should be attached to your component. The binding of those two functions must be done via `on-click` attribute and *not* via `onclick` as you currently have.